# BackgroundWorker stops the WPF UI to be refreshed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, backgroundworker

Some time ago I wrote a simple application with the WPF-based UI that uses the BackgroundWorker:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            foreach (TechNews news in (e.Result as List<TechNews>))
            {
                NewsListBox.Items.Add(news);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        CNetTechNewsParser parser = new CNetTechNewsParser();
        parser.Parse();
        e.Result = parser.News;
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly then. But now I have launched it again and found that the UI stops refreshing, i.e. LoadTextBlock doesn't disappear and news doesn't showed in the list box. It refreshes only after I minimize the app.

I removed all parsing functionality from the DoWork but got the same effect. Then commented RunWorkerAsync and the UI started work normally. So I suggest the problem is caused by the BackgroundWorker. But I can't understand what is wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: What is thread context of worker_RunWorkerCompleted function? Possibly this function executes incorrect cross-thread operation. Try Dispatcher.BeginInvoke for UI update instead of direct control access.

Comment: @AlexFarber tried Dispatcher.Invoke previously and had no luck. Now tried your variant and voila - it works! But even more interesting, I tried a direct access again - and now it works too! That's mysterious... Anyway, thanks for the answer, the problem looks to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit puzzled that no invalid-cross-thread error is thrown (UnauthorizedAccessException), but nonetheless you could use an extension method that calls your UI Update logic on the correct dispatcher for the target control.

```
public static class WindowExtensions
{
        public static void Dispatch(this Control control, Action action)
        {
            if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                action();
            else
                control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
        }
}
```

Usage would be this in your case:

```
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatch(() =>
    {
        LoadTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            foreach (TechNews news in (e.Result as List<TechNews>))
            {
                NewsListBox.Items.Add(news);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, "Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As I understand, the RunWorkerCompleted event handler is run by the thread that have created a BackgroundWorker, i.e. the UI thread in my case so no cross-thread operations are needed. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx). "The background thread runs your DoWork event handler, and the thread that creates your controls runs your ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted event handlers"